# Choosing sealed subclass based on field value in Kotlinx Serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization, polymorphism, kotlinx.serialization

Is there a way to distinguish between `Successful` and `Failed` responses based on the value of `ok` field in a response JSON?

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class Response {
    @Serializable
    data class Successful(
        @SerialName("ok")
        val ok: Boolean,

        @SerialName("payload")
        val payload: Payload
    ) : Response()

    @Serializable
    data class Failed(
        @SerialName("ok")
        val ok: Boolean,

        @SerialName("description")
        val description: String
    ) : Response()
}
```

So, for `{"ok":true, "payload":…}` I want to get `Successful` class, and for `{"ok":false, "description":…}` — `Failed`.

I know that there is similar question — [Deserializing into sealed subclass based on value of field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59743124/750510) — but it uses `type` field, and I don't have any type discriminators in the JSON (the **meaning** of `ok` is not type discrimination (though it can be used that way with some hacks, probably))

Comment: Have you tried creating a Custom serializer for `Response`? https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md

Comment: Any examples of how to write it? I think I may need something like `kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractPolymorphicSerializer`. The problem is that in it's case values are stored as `{"type": "Type Descriptor", "value": {...}}`, and I may need some kind of a lookahead into the value.